# Socket does not connect when using ssl certificate generatd by lestencrypt nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am running an https server using a certificate which was created using lets encrypt.

Now I want to connect Socket.io client to the Socket.io server that is attached to the https server. Unfortunately, the socket just simplify disconnects without any error. I have tried everything possible but haven't been able to figure out the problem. Here's my code.

Server Side:

```
const options = envResolver.isLocal ? {} : {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../cert/key.pem")),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../cert/cert.pem")),
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}

const server = envResolver.isLocal ? http.createServer(app) : https.createServer(options, app)


const io = new Server(httpServer,  {
     pingInterval: 2000,
     pingTimeout: 5000
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  process.send && process.send("ready")
  winston.info(
    `Express app named ${serverName} started on port ${process.env.PORT} with env ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
  )
})
```

Code for Client Side:

```
const certPem = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
server crt file string
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    `
this.socket = io('wss://<url>:3004', {
      transports: ['websocket'],
      query: this.apiHeader,
      ca: certPem.toString(),
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      secure: true
});
```

Have temporarily stored the server's cert.pem file in a template string. Will figure out later how to load server cert file.

How can I make Socket.io connect in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the certificates, you should let it on the server side. You don't need the certPem on the client side.
You should look at the console and network tabs in the develop tools, it's always insightful.

Here a simple example in Nodejs. Your approach should works though on the server, I am not sure what is the problem, maybe it is on the client side.

```javascript
const fs=require('fs')
const https=require("https")
const express=require('express')
const app=express();
const sokcetIO = require('socket.io')
const port=443;
const options={
    key:fs.readFileSync("../privkey.pem"),
    cert:fs.readFileSync("../cert.pem")
  }
const server=https.createServer(options,app)
const io=sokcetIO(server)
server.listen(port)
app.use(express.static('public'))
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    socket.emit('greeting-from-server', {
        greeting: 'Hello Client'
    });
    socket.on('greeting-from-client', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
      });
})
```

And a simple HTML page, in the public static folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello websocket</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello websocket
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-/KNQL8Nu5gCHLqwqfQjA689Hhoqgi2S84SNUxC3roTe4EhJ9AfLkp8QiQcU8AMzI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io("https://localhost:443");
    socket.on('greeting-from-server', function (message) {
                    console.log(message.greeting)
                socket.emit('greeting-from-client', {
                    greeting: 'Hello Server'
                });
            });
</script>
</html>
```

I more or less followed this [tutorial](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781785880865/1/ch01lvl1sec10/creating-a-node-http-server-with-socket-io) for the payload, endpoint on the websocket server and client

You can already test this simple example

---

For angular, I tested this simple [tutorial](https://deepinder.me/creating-a-real-time-app-with-angular-8-and-socket-io-with-nodejs) and it worked fine.
Only one "problem" to note, the article used an old angular version.

If you are using a recent version like 15, you have to change the part about the environment file, as angular 15 does not provide it. I simply write the websocket server endpoint in the angular websocket service.

Hope it helps !